# add_rewrite_rule not working in Custom Post Type UI Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I created custom post using Custom Post Type UI Plugin.

The post type name was: **recruit**

Now my current URL is: **http://wordpress-603.com/?recruit=top**
[image]

I want to change it  to **http://wordpress-603.com/recruit/top**
[image]

I tried this rewrite rule and added on my function.php but it seems not working(also tried to re-save permalink to flush).

```
add_rewrite_rule( "recruit/?$", "index.php?post_type=recruit", 'top' );
add_rewrite_rule( '^recruit/([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?recruit=$matches[1]', 'top' );
add_rewrite_rule( '^recruit/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php/?post_type=recruit&name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

I have this CPT UI:

```
{
    "recruit": {
        "name": "recruit",
        "label": "RECRUIT",
        "singular_label": "recruit",
        "description": "",
        "public": "true",
        "publicly_queryable": "true",
        "show_ui": "true",
        "show_in_nav_menus": "true",
        "delete_with_user": "false",
        "show_in_rest": "true",
        "rest_base": "",
        "rest_controller_class": "",
        "has_archive": "true",
        "has_archive_string": "",
        "exclude_from_search": "false",
        "capability_type": "post",
        "hierarchical": "false",
        "rewrite": "true",
        "rewrite_slug": "",
        "rewrite_withfront": "false",
        "query_var": "true",
        "query_var_slug": "",
        "menu_position": "",
        "show_in_menu": "true",
        "show_in_menu_string": "",
        "menu_icon": "",
        "supports": [
            "title",
            "custom-fields",
            "revisions",
            "post-formats"
        ],
        "taxonomies": [
            "category"
        ],
        "labels": {
            "menu_name": "",
            "all_items": "",
            "add_new": "",
            "add_new_item": "",
            "edit_item": "",
            "new_item": "",
            "view_item": "",
            "view_items": "",
            "search_items": "",
            "not_found": "",
            "not_found_in_trash": "",
            "parent_item_colon": "",
            "featured_image": "",
            "set_featured_image": "",
            "remove_featured_image": "",
            "use_featured_image": "",
            "archives": "",
            "insert_into_item": "",
            "uploaded_to_this_item": "",
            "filter_items_list": "",
            "items_list_navigation": "",
            "items_list": "",
            "attributes": "",
            "name_admin_bar": "",
            "item_published": "",
            "item_published_privately": "",
            "item_reverted_to_draft": "",
            "item_scheduled": "",
            "item_updated": ""
        },
        "custom_supports": ""
    }
}
```

My Permalink Setting is:

[image]

It is easy way to used **Post name** on Common Settings but other custom post type should be using the plain and only the post_type:recruit will be rewrite.

Please Help me achieve my required link.